# NameError: undefined local variable or method in irb

Tags: ruby, terminal, arguments, irb, nameerror

I am using ruby 1.9.2 with irb and I keep getting the following error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ex1' for main:Object
from (irb):4
from /Users/flexmaster411/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried to drag and drop into irb then I get another argument error the code.

```
Rodas-MacBook-Air:~ flexmaster411$ pwd /Users/flexmaster411
Rodas-MacBook-Air:~ flexmaster411$ cd Desktop
Rodas-MacBook-Air:Desktop flexmaster411$ cd my
Rodas-MacBook-Air:my flexmaster411$ ls
ex1.rb ex2.rb   test.html   test.rb  wacky.rb
Rodas-MacBook-Air:my flexmaster411$ irb
1.9.2-p320 :001 > ruby ex1.rb
NameError: undefined local variable or method ex1' for main:Object from (irb):1 from /Users/flexmaster411/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in <main>'
```

Comment: Please add the actual code you tried to execute, otherwise we won't be able to come up with a helpful answer.

Comment: I get the same error message no matter what code I put in but in this case it is puts "Hello World!"

Comment: Ok, could you please update your answer with the complete irb session then? Including the line where you start irb and including the complete error message. Thanks

Comment: Here is the start of the irb session 1.9.2p320 :001 > ruby ex1.rb
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ex1' for main:Object
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/flexmaster411/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2p320 :002 >                                                 appreciate your help.

Comment: No he means add all the code from the moment you typed `irb` up until the error to your question.

Comment: Rodas-MacBook-Air:~ flexmaster411$ pwd
/Users/flexmaster411
Rodas-MacBook-Air:~ flexmaster411$ cd Desktop
Rodas-MacBook-Air:Desktop flexmaster411$ cd my
Rodas-MacBook-Air:my flexmaster411$ ls
ex1.rb  ex2.rb  test.html test.rb  wacky.rb
Rodas-MacBook-Air:my flexmaster411$ irb
1.9.2-p320 :001 > ruby ex1.rb
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ex1' for main:Object
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/flexmaster411/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p320 :002 >

Comment: You can also edit your question and put the content properly formatted in there

Comment: Never mind, i got the problem, let me just write up the answer real quick

Comment: I've added your code to your question (and hopefully formatted it correctly), in the future please do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you were trying to do was:

```
$ irb
001 > ruby ex1.rb
```

The `ruby` command is a program on its own, so you should use `ruby` directly from the command line like this:

```
$ ruby ex1.rb
```

This means “Ruby, please execute this file”, whereas `irb` is a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), awaiting Ruby statements directly. This means you could type your Ruby code directly into irb like this:

```
$ irb
001 > puts "Hello, world!"
Hello, world!
```

Or you could go into `irb` and load the contents of the file and then experiment with the code:

```
$ irb
001 > require './ex1'
```

Comment: Totally didn't catch this big thanks again padde for clearing it up.